# how to make radio button options unchanged, even after some changes made in other parts of a page in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have dropdown rows in a table, each row have 3 radio buttons. i want the selected radio options value to be unchanged, even if navigate between the rows. it is done in vuejs.

option 1 
             option 2 
 option 3

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Tell us what you have tried and give some code to help others to help you